# Difference between `strace -r` and `strace -T` options?

Tags: linux, system-calls, strace, statistics

What's the difference between the two? In the man pages it says:

```
   -r          Print a relative timestamp upon entry to each system call.  This records the time difference between  the  beginning  of
               successive system calls.

   -T          Show the time spent in system calls.  This records the time difference between the beginning and the end of each  system
               call.
```

My only interpretation is that `-T` shows the time taken just for each call, whereas `-r` also takes into account any time spent waiting after each syscall.

This seems to be supported by the fact that when looking at corresponding snippets of an `strace` on the `uptime` command, the `-r` command is showing longer times per call than `-T` below. See below:

```
0.000039 uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="ip-172-31-55-20", ...}) = 0
0.000043 open("/sys/devices/system/cpu/online", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
0.000045 read(3, "0\n", 8192)      = 2
0.000035 close(3)                  = 0
```

&

```
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="ip-172-31-55-20", ...}) = 0 <0.000010>
open("/sys/devices/system/cpu/online", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000018>
read(3, "0\n", 8192)                    = 2 <0.000014>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000023>
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much right, yes.

The extra time shown by `-r` isn't time spent waiting, it's time doing other things which don't involve syscalls (calculations, memory manipulations...).

Answer (score 0):

Considering this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38129424/6492953), among with calculations and other stuff like that, there must be some time spent by **strace** itself.

The way **strace** works cause kernel to halt program being traced at the beggining and at the end of each system call, so **strace** can inspect it and then resume execution.

So the time difference between the beginning of successive system calls must include some time spent by the **strace** itself.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind adding a few more words of explanation,otherwise the answer is not really different from that by @StephenKitt, who implied the same?